# Copying multiple files in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script of which finds all files by name then copies and renames them, I want it to make a copy of multiple files (all of which have the same name) then rename them to the same original name. Currently, it mostly functions as it finds the files by name but it only copies the first file and ignores the rest. My current script is as follows

```js
function copyDocs() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('PlaceHolder').next();
  file.makeCopy('PlaceHolder');
}
```

I myself am not the most educated on this type of language or any coding language, to be honest, so I'm sorry if this is an easy solution or rookie mistake.

Comment: You’re only copying the first one because you’re not using that he hasnext iterator. Try while files.hasNext()

Comment: @Cooper I inserted this into the script but now I get this error                     TypeError: Cannot call method "makeCopy" of undefined. (line 17, file "Code")         This is the new code                                                                                         
function copyDocs() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('PlaceHolder');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  files.next().file.makeCopy('PlaceHolder');
  }}

Comment: @Cooper I take back what I just said I figured it out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So did your question get solved? If that's the case, please consider posting an answer explaining what you did to solve this, as it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DriveApp.getFilesByName(...)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)) returns a [`FileIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator.html). You need to iterate over all of the found files.

```
function copyDocs()
{
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('PlaceHolder');
    while(files.hasNext())
    {
        files.next().makeCopy("PlaceHolder");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I had found a solution like this I'm glad for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved with help from @Cooper and @IMTheNachoMan. I simply needed to use the while(files.hasNext) iterator before placing makeCopy("PlaceHolder"). The end script is as follows

```js
function copyDocs() {
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('PlaceHolder');
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   files.next().makeCopy('PlaceHolder');
   }
}
```